# Powershell - any recommendations for modules that emulate bash commands?

Tags: bash, powershell

I've recently started out using powershell.  It's a bit hard to get started with but seems powerful enough.

What I am wondering is if there is a github project or equivalent to emulate some of the more useful **bash** commands and their parameters.

For example, **find** has a lot of power under the hood, with things like `find . -cmin -20` (get files changed in the last 20 minutes).  Sure, I created a quick function to do it in the current directory:

```
function findcmin($cmin=30)
{
    Get-ChildItem . -r | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addMinutes(-$cmin)} | Select-Object fullname
}
```

But is there an existing project that does this type of emulation/porting, with **cmin** being an option of **find**?  Ditto for wrapping **select-string** look to make it into a **grep** lookalike.

There is already some of that built into powershell, that's why **ls** behaves like **get-childitem**.

Anyone know of more?

Comment: Nice idea, that made me immediately [run a quick check on Github](https://github.com/search?q=powershell%20bash&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1). Results might interest you :) Apart from that: just "more" is a bit broad. Anything specific you want to see covered? Or "as close to the full set as possible"? Any price tag, just in case?

Comment: yes, you are right, I could have searched through GitHub.  But, as you can see from your own search results, what I have in mind is easier explained than searched for.  For example, you have node.js module which obviously has nothing to do with it.  That's why I thought of asking here first.  The top 10 or so hits (sorted by stars) don't seem all that promising.

Comment: Agreed: I've posted my comment before I had evaluated the results, and some titles looked more promising than the content behind. If I had asked that question, it would be "a PS module that imitates Bash, so I can have Bash code run by PS" – but it's your question, so I won't rewrite it :)

Comment: Can you use Windows 10's [built in Bash shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be the gnuWin32 collection which was Win32 compiled versions of the various textutils, fileutils, coreutils, etc.  This is what you are after, I think....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no.  Really more interested in utilities written *in powershell* that give a bit more bash power within a powershell environment.  For another example, `which foo` would be neat to have, and it would *just* require trawling through the path to get most of its functionality.

Comment: As JL pointed out he's after Powershell modules – not after "anything to run *nix commands". While you can install "anything" on your own machine, you rarely can do that on company machines where you might need to "write stuff that runs on production". Powershell modules are more likely to be accepted in that context. Just one example, and from my perspective – I don't know whether the OPs context might be different :)